# passing in a property key as a generic argument in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-8ltel?file=/index.ts:0-283) and here is the code:

```
type Tags = "TAG1" | "TAG2";

export type S<Tag extends Tags> = {
  tag: Tag;
  get<K, R>(k: K): R;
};

const store = {
  one: "ONE"
};

type Keys = keyof typeof store;

const s: S<"TAG1"> = {
  tag: "TAG1",
  get<K extends Keys>(k: K) {
    return store[k];
  }
};
```

I get an error with `get<K extends Keys>(k: K) {`

> Type '<K extends "one">(k: K) => { one: string; }[K]' is not assignable to type '<K, R>(k: K) => R'.
> Types of parameters 'k' and 'k' are incompatible.
> Type 'K' is not assignable to type '"one"'.ts(2322

Can I type passing in a key value like this?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use generic as a return type

```js
type Tags = "TAG1" | "TAG2";

export type S<Tag extends Tags> = {
  tag: Tag;
  get<K extends Keys>(k: K): Store[K];
};

const store = {
  one: "ONE"
};

type Store = typeof store
type Keys = keyof typeof store;

const s: S<"TAG1"> = {
  tag: "TAG1",
  get<K extends Keys>(k: K):Store[K] {
    return store[k];
  }
};

const x = s.get('one') // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgcwM5QLxQEQwIIHECMGUAPpjrgEwYDcAULRAB5gD2ATsFKJFAMoA88BFCbAIAOwAmKIUgB8aKAG9aULogBcsRHTUIIwfgGkRjMVJRGIIeQAoA1lqMBKLb2DsIAbSMBdOgC%20dLQAxiziSJyRnooqauEQWhgA8gByAKIYtEH03NDuMeh5LABmUNFsELR5UFY2ivbWpVzgEM0VEMFhEVFu-Fh4hAroceoISeSEADSqUPqGJqIS0rXWdo61rgWVPr7Ks2qVwACubOLlHjv2-rMB2V3hkVCMikgAdPO2AOQJX85QAHoARc2ABLcQIIA)